# On the existance of two random variables given tree conditions

Tags: probability, distributions, mean, random-variable

Can anyone give a example, or show that none exist, of two random variables $X$ and $Y$ such that:

1. $X$ has finite mean $\mu_X$, and $Y$ also has finite mean $\mu_Y$.
2. $\mu_X < \mu_Y$.
3. $\mathbb{P}(X > Y) > 0.5$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let Y take on the following values 1 (probability $\frac{1}{3}$), 2 (probability $\frac{1}{3}$), 12 (probability $\frac{1}{3}$).  $\mu_y=5$

Let X take on the following values 3 (probability $\frac{1}{3}$), 4 (probability $\frac{1}{3}$), 5 (probability $\frac{1}{3}$).  $\mu_x=4$

$P(X>Y) = 1-P(y=12) = 1-\frac{1}{3} =\frac{2}{3} > \frac{1}{2}$

Answer (score 1):

If you allow a single possible value of X to get really negative, then you can cook up a scenario that works.

Let $Y$ be a constant, $Y = 0$, and let $X$ take the value $1$ with $0.9$ probability and the value $-100$ with $0.1$ probability. Then $E[X] = \mu_X = 0.9(1) + 0.1(-100) = -9.1 < E[Y] = \mu_Y = 0$, but $P(X>Y) = P(X>0) = 0.9 >0.5$